# AngularJS - putObject with a function. function not stored in cookie?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I have the following:

```
$scope.powerUps = [
    { id: "a", name: "+1 Click", cpsEffect: 0, clickEffect:  1, cost:10, 
      costMultiplier: 1.2, active : true, 
      buy: function(){
           $scope.clickValue += 1;
           $scope.counter = Math.round($scope.counter - this.cost);
           this.cost = Math.round((this.cost * this.costMultiplier));
           $cookies.putObject("powerUps",$scope.powerUps);
      }
    }, ... 
]
```

When looking at the saved cookie after using `$cookies.putObject` or retrieving it with `$cookies.getObject` I am finding that everything is present except for the "buy" function. Is this an Angular quirk? Or something more fundamental that I don't know about?

Comment: Why are you trying to store a function in a cookie?

Comment: Each of the powerUp objects will have different behaviour on the buy function. I'm  trying to store them as cookies so when returning to the page I can pull in what ones were active for the user, and what their current cost was. I guess i could put the function outside the scope of an individual powerUp, but just got a  bit confused as to why everything was in the cookie except the function.

Comment: Cookies are strings. The `.putObject` method serializes objects to a string. Functions don't serialize. That's why the `.putObject` method does not store functions in cookies.

Comment: Hey, thank you. I'm going to take the function out of each powerUp.